# Node.js Express 3.x passing variables to views

Tags: node.js, templates, view, express

You can expose data to views using: app.local and res.locals. Does someone know exactly what the difference between the two is? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the express.js API Doc:

#### app.locals

> Application local variables are provided to all templates rendered within the application. This is useful for providing helper functions to templates, as well as app-level data.

#### res.locals

> Response local variables are scoped to the request, thus only available to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle, if any. Otherwise this API is identical to app.locals.

This means the only difference is that res.locals are only valid for the lifetime of the request.